# git subtree add does not accept pathspec

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm trying to add a vim plugin in my settings repo as a git subtree. No matter where I try to pull the subtree to, git replies with an `error: pathspec`

I'm using the command below while at repos root directory:

```
git subtree add --prefix .vim/bundle/powerline powerline master --squash
```

which results in output:

```
git fetch powerline master
From git://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: pathspec '.vim/bundle/powerline' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I'm using git version 2.0.3

Comment: This was also happening for me but it turned out to be because the --prefix I was using had a backslash in it... It works for me with regular slash...

Comment: Have you tried funning git fetch --all before git subtree add ?

Comment: I tried to setup my repo from scratch. This time everything worked fine. Not sure what was the problem previously, but I think I could have an repo without the initial commit.

Comment: For me (git 2.34.1), it was because the remote repo I added was empty (I had just created it, with intention to fill it). So I had to create a dummy.txt in the remote repo just to get `subtree add` to work correctly .

Answer (score 28):

I had exactly the same problem, turns out it was the "."

```
 git subtree add --prefix ./cs/ControlLibrary/ ControlLibrary master --squash
```

Failed with:

```
error: pathspec './cs/ControlLibrary' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

but

```
git subtree add --prefix cs/ControlLibrary/ ControlLibrary master --squash
```

worked just fine :)

I am on Windows using ConEmu, not sure if that made any difference

Comment: Similar problem in linux, removing the `./` from the prefix solved it.